# Flutter center suffix icon text

Tags: flutter, dart

I am showing Text in TextFormField as a suffix icon but the issue is it's not showing in the center. If I give padding maybe it will not responsive in all screen sizes.

My code

```
Container(
    width:
        Width * 0.4,
    child:
        TextFormField(
      textAlignVertical:
          TextAlignVertical
              .center,
      controller:
          servicePriceInput,
      inputFormatters: [
        WhitelistingTextInputFormatter(
            RegExp(
                "[0-9 .]")),
      ],
      decoration:
          new InputDecoration(
        labelText:
            "Price",
        suffixIcon:
            Text(
          currencySet ==
                  1
              ? r"$"
              : currencySet == 2
                  ? r"AED"
                  : currencySet == 3
                      ? r"PKR"
                      : currencySet == 4
                          ? r"SR"
                          : currencySet == 5
                              ? r"£"
                              : '',
          style: TextStyle(
              color:
                  kPrimaryColor,
              fontFamily:
                  'SegoeUI-Bold'),
        ),
        labelStyle: TextStyle(
            color:
                textGreyColor,
            fontFamily:
                'SegoeUI'),
        fillColor:
            Colors
                .white,
        focusedBorder:
            OutlineInputBorder(
          borderSide: BorderSide(
              color:
                  kPrimaryColor,
              width:
                  1.0),
        ),
        enabledBorder:
            OutlineInputBorder(
          borderSide: BorderSide(
              color: Color(
                  0xffE6E6E6),
              width:
                  1.0),
        ),

        border:
            new OutlineInputBorder(
          borderRadius:
              new BorderRadius.circular(
                  10),
          borderSide:
              new BorderSide(
                  color: Color(0xffE6E6E6)),
        ),
        //fillColor: Colors.green
      ),
      keyboardType:
          TextInputType
              .number,
      style: new TextStyle(
          fontFamily:
              "SegoeUI",
          color:
              kPrimaryColor),
    ),
  ),
```

You can see in image AED is showing above my text field text. I want to show it in the center with text. I try isCollapsed and textAlignVertical but not working.

[image]

Comment: try my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69127867/13997210) hope its help to you

Answer (score 2):

Use suffix instead of suffixIcon. It will solve your problem

Answer (score 1):

Just suffixIcon . Did for me . No need of Padding and other stuff until you required .

Answer (score 0):

Use can try this:

```
SuffixIconConstraints:BoxConstrains(
maxHeight:double.infinity
)
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use top and bottom `Padding` for the icon, like this:

```
suffixIcon:
    Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 2.5, bottom: 2.5),
        Text(
      currencySet ==
              1
          ? r"$"
          : currencySet == 2
              ? r"AED"
              : currencySet == 3
                  ? r"PKR"
                  : currencySet == 4
                      ? r"SR"
                      : currencySet == 5
                          ? r"£"
                          : '',
        style: TextStyle(
          color:
              kPrimaryColor,
          fontFamily:
              'SegoeUI-Bold'),
    ))
```

Answer (score -3):

You can wrap the Text in a `Center.